# send messages via Bluetooth using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, swift4, ios-bluetooth

I would to like to develop a messaging app that uses Bluetooth.

Are there any easy frameworks for using Bluetooth in Swift?

This app needs to be able to message other iOS devices.

I've searched but couldn't find any real help for this problem.

Comment: You can use Core Bluetooth or Multipeer Connectivity frameworks, unfortunately your question as it stands is too broad for a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Apple's framework "MultipeerConnectivity". Not only you can send text messages but you can send any image/video/files in form of binary data using this framework. Again not only bluetooth but you can also use wifi for the purpose.

See details:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, indeed!**

You can use Core Bluetooth to chat to both ios and android devices from ios.

Here is a brilliant example:  [Who's there application](https://itnext.io/whos-there-simple-swift-app-for-chatting-with-colleagues-around-a88ff765736f)

Comment: How? In example is not showing how to communicate with Android.